# Project runs on MacBook, but crashes on iMac

Tags: ios, swift

Created this simple test project because I was having trouble in another one. Crashes on my iMac [EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)], works fine on my MacBook - rectangle resizes and centers.

This is almost the entire project:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myRect: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myRect.frame.size.width = 200
    myRect.frame.size.height = 400
    myRect.center = myRect.superview!.center
    myRect.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
}
```

Comment: Can we assume you are running the iOS Simulator on the two Macs? Are you using the same version of Xcode? Are you running the same simulated iOS device with the same version of iOS?

Comment: Can you post the entire error message verbatim not just the small subsection of EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Also, which line causes the exception?